# MYSQL Select Count if greater than 0

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a way i can count all the greater than 0 in late?

```
Select *, timestampdiff(minute, t1.startTime, t.IOTime) as late from tbl_time GROUP BY name
```

if the late returns higher than 0 then it should count.

```
Select *, COUNT(timestampdiff(minute, t1.startTime, t.IOTime)) as late from tbl_time
```

but I don't know how to make it's condition

example of my data:

```
tbl_time
name     timeIn  date
Chris    9:50    2015-02-11    
Chris    9:30    2015-02-12    
Chris    9:20    2015-02-13
```

in other table is where the startTime

```
tbl_employee
name     startTime
Chris    9:25
```

So in timestamp it returns how many minutes he's late I would like to have a return value that counts all the timestamp that return greater than 0 so i can count all his total late

```
name    total_late
Chris   2
```

this is what my code is

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select name, SUM(late) as total from(SELECT name, CASE WHEN timestampdiff(minute, t1.startTime, t.timeIn)>0 THEN 1 END AS late FROM tbl_time )  t JOIN tbl_employee t1 ON t.name = t1.name GROUP BY name");
```

Comment: Can you reword your question maybe? I can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: the code i gave returns how many minutes he's late. I would like to get how many total he got a late in entire month. so I need to count every time that code returns higher than 0

Comment: What are the other columns in tbl_time? What is a "he"?

Comment: edited a sample data

Comment: Are startTime and IOTime in different tables or not?

Comment: different. IOTime is what time he arrive. that's why it has Join names but didn't include it cause too long. I just need to count all he's late using the return of the timestamp

Comment: I just don't know how to make condition or something just to count all his late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `CASE` statement. See below:

```
SELECT name, SUM(late) AS total_late
(
SELECT B.name,
       CASE WHEN timestampdiff(minute, A.startTime, B.timeIn)>0 THEN 1 END AS late 
FROM tbl_employee A LEFT JOIN tbl_time B ON A.name=B.name
) AS Count_Late GROUP BY name
```

Comment: ahm can you do the join too please. I keep getting error from the t1.startTime it said that error inconnu dans field list

Comment: You just need to convert A.startTime and B.timeIn. Your welcome, I'm happy to help.^_^